# IOS Push Notification doesn't work using PushSharp

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

Im using PushSHarp on my project via Nuget and VisualStudio (c#) to try to send  push notification through APN.

I created all of the file that required using my Apple account(development certificate, .p12 files etc).

Each time i used the right code i stil have the same error( i recreated all of the thing to be sure my token id is not bad):

> ID= 1 Code= ConnectionError
>   PushSharp.Common.NotificationException: Invalid DeviceToken    à
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApnsNotification.ToBytes()    à
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.createBatch(List`1 toSend)    à
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<SendBatch>d__21.MoveNext() Message
>   Apns notification error: 'ConnectionError' String
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApnsNotificationException: Apns notification error:
>   'ConnectionError' ---> PushSharp.Common.NotificationException: Invalid
>   DeviceToken    à PushSharp.Apple.ApnsNotification.ToBytes()    à
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.createBatch(List`1 toSend)    à
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.d__21.MoveNext()

Can you help me in this issue please? i really dont understand what happened.

I am using the below code given in their git wiki page to send the notifications here is the code

```
string TokenId = "f38205ce2137862735bd32e85b581dc85e2dc0abc04a2702e2899bddb9114543";

         PushNotificationApple _notifservice = new PushNotificationApple();

                _notifservice.SendAppleNotification(TokenId, "Test1");

    public void SendAppleNotification(string tokenId, string message)
            {
                byte[] appleCert = null;

                try
                {
                    appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes("F:\\Dev\\ap.p12");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OK LECTURE APPLE CERT");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var toto = ex.Message;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" Exception lecture"+ ex.Message);
                }

                // Configuration (NOTE: .pfx can also be used here)
                var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, appleCert, "BrumbySolution99");

                // Create a new broker
                var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);

                // Wire up events
                apnsBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) =>
                {

                    aggregateEx.Handle(ex =>
                    {

                        // See what kind of exception it was to further diagnose
                        if (ex is ApnsNotificationException)
                        {

                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERRREUR NOTIFICATION");
                            var notificationException = (ApnsNotificationException)ex;

                            // Deal with the failed notification
                            var apnsNotification = notificationException.Notification;
                            var statusCode = notificationException.ErrorStatusCode;

                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Apple Notification Failed: ID= " + notificationException.Notification.Identifier+" Code= "+ statusCode);
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("link "+  ex.HelpLink);
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Inner "+  ex.InnerException);
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message " + ex.Message);
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("String " + ex.ToString());

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Inner exception might hold more useful information like an ApnsConnectionException           
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Apple Notification Failed for some unknown reason : {ex.InnerException}");

                        }

                        // Mark it as handled
                        return true;
                    });
                };

                apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("APPLE NOTIFICATION SENT");
                   // Console.WriteLine("Apple Notification Sent!");
                };

                // Start the broker
                apnsBroker.Start();


                var notification_message = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"title\":\" Title " + message + "\",\"body\":\"Body " + message + "\"},\"badge\":\"1\"}}";
                // Queue a notification to send
                apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
                {
                    DeviceToken = tokenId,
                    Payload = JObject.Parse(notification_message)

                });

                // Stop the broker, wait for it to finish   
                // This isn't done after every message, but after you're
                // done with the broker
                apnsBroker.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where did you get the value in your var TokenId?

Comment: Yes, the error does indicate a bad token. `PushSharp.Common.NotificationException: Invalid
  DeviceToken`

Comment: Make sure that token is correct, but also make sure that the app is build using the Development Profile/Certificate (ie. the type you load onto your device via a cable and debug, not distributed through the App Store of via an enterprise publication) and that the app is using a Dev Push Notification certificate. This is because you have specified the Sandbox server when starting up PushSharp and therefore it's expecting a token that's valid against the development configuration

Comment: i put some code in my app to get token id of the phone. i use visual studio i dont have any mac. Do you think its not good? @ChrisTerry

Comment: No, that should be an ok way to do it, but it looks like the PushSharp bits are fine, it's just the token that's the problem. Easiest thing to try first is change the Sandbox option to Production and see if it works. If your app is using a production Push Notification profile then that would explain the problem. If that doesn't work change it back and intvestigate the configuration at your app end, make sure if has the Push Notification privelages and development certificates and profiles for push notifications. Also check you took the token down correctly.

Comment: @ChrisTerry you were right my cerficate wasn't good. i suceed now to sned some notificatioN. really thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all @picciano too

Comment: Great, thanks for the update